# Disabling the special meaning of either `+` and/or `|`

Tags: org-table, org-link, org-ref

I came across a case where strike-through and table interfere with the proper operation of org-links (which, in my case are org-ref citations). Here is a minimal example:

```
+-+
|cite:VemulaMO2016c-Path-Plann
```

This link is dead. However, if any of the four other characters is removed, the link comes alive. Whether this is a bug or not, can I somehow disable the special meaning of either `+` or `|` (not just the mark-up and highlighting) for the current buffer?

Comment: As standard `cite:...` is never a link.  Using `http://...` works fine for me.

Comment: @AndrewSwann In `org-ref`, `cite:` is defined using `org-link-set-parameters`.

Comment: Then you should us your set-up as `org-ref` is not in the standard orgmode bundle.